# How can I play a sound from Raw folder in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing an app where I have a Fragment for a Level Complete and I want to play a sound when this Fragment loads.

I think that I have to write the MediaPlayer in the onCreate method but I don't know exactly how to write the MediaPlayer code.

I've already loaded the mp3 file in the Raw Folder

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, R.raw.some_file);
player.start();
```